# always getting innerHTML of div empty after loading a php page although successfully loaded

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i m loading a div through jquery

```
$('#Detailvolunteer').load("http://localhost/../somepage.php")
```

now after load i get the div content empty although it has loaded successfully.the innerHTML shows nothing. what i want is to check the data and hide the div if empty . but it always shows empty.

Comment: Please show more codes

Answer (score 1):

you need to proviade a callback function for load.  [Load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

> If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after
>   post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed. The callback is
>   fired once for each element in the jQuery collection, and this is set
>   to each DOM element in turn.

```
$('#Detailvolunteer').load("http://localhost/../somepage.php",function(data){
   //hrere do some logic to replace. 
});
```

or even better use like this

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

When this method executes, it retrieves the content of ajax/test.html, but then jQuery parses the returned document to find the element with an ID of container. This element, along with its contents, is inserted into the element with an ID of result, and the rest of the retrieved document is discarded.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply ..done both the above ways but still when  alerting the value it shows nothing

Comment: @KandarpPatel is there any other errors ? or are u sure you are returning correct data

Comment: no errors . but i got a thing if i set on click evnt it shows the data.what i want is to check on document.load if it is empty coz on that i want to hide another div.